# Embed Image inside webpage

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm new to developing Chrome Extensions, but have programming experience. I would like to know if it is possible to embed an external image in every website that the user visits?

e.g. a small banner image at the top of every website, I have looked into 'content scripts' but I'm not sure if the image has to be on the website directory already or if you can load an external image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Short answer:

YES!

### Long answer:

Yes, you can use an external image. But you I'd not recommend to you, for example, inject an `<img>` tag in the page. I've experienced some cross-domain errors eventually with this method.

That's the way I do:

First of all you should add the image host domain into the manifest permissions.

**manifest.json**:

```
{
...
"permissions": ["http://image-domain.com/images/*"]
...
}
```

Then load the image **from the extension domain** and inject the **image data** in some `<img>` tag.

Hope it helps...

Comment: Cross domain errors? The website shoudl display <img src="http://mywebpage.com/myimage.php> even if the website is 'notmysite.com'

Comment: @GregValantine Yes, you're kinda right. But this method has some limitations and eventually some cross-domain errors.

Comment: Could you care to explain, is it possible? I'm just trying to embed adverts in certain webpages.

Comment: @GregValantine Just imagine some complex webpages like facebook or webpages that use certain google analytics  scripts... they have a lot of event listeners for images that are supposed to be in the same domain. This is how i've experienced some of those errors.

The limitations of this method are caused for the same reason: scripts  can't load external resources and extensions can only load resources from permitted domains. 

Don't forget this is only a recommendation. Cheers.

Comment: Yeah ok, what happens if the script was to only run on certain websites then...? Have you got any code examples?

Comment: And injecting images from non-https domains to a https website results in some warnings.